# SPF Authentication Failed

Tags: email, authentication, server, spf, exim

I'm experiencing a deliverability problem according to the MXToolBox email deliverability tool:

> SPF Authentication    SPF Failed for IP - 169.179.203.116

Current SPF record on my domain is:

```
v=spf1 +mx +a +ip4:116.203.179.169 ~all
```

Please guide me to resolve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the `169.179.203.116` address is one that is known to you.

A better SPF record that will result in a pass for that IP:

```
v=spf1 ip4:169.179.203.116 ip4:116.203.179.169 a mx ~all
```

It's good practice to put literal IPs first as mechanisms are evaluated left to right, and literal IPs do not require DNS lookups, so are the fastest for receivers to check.

Generally, you need to be sure that the IPs you are sending from are listed, or covered by some other mechanism (e.g. by using an `include` from an email service provider).